# How to write a loading code to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void save(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    for (Club club : clubs)
        pw.println(club.getName());
    pw.close();
}
```

This will write the name of each club on a new line in your file.

- Soccer
- Chess
- Football
- Volleyball

How do I write a loading code to an `ArrayList`?
`clubs` may not contain only `String` as well as `Integer`.

Comment: Did you try anything? You can start by checking FileInputStream and BufferedReader

Comment: What does it mean that clubs may contain Integer? Does it just mean that some of the club names are numeric?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to ask a good question, as well as guidelines as to what you should do before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but I'll give it a shot.

Create a BufferedReader object that points to the file you want to load from.  Read the contents line by line.  Split each line on ' ' and add each element to an array list of type String.

Comment: My guess is the OP wants a `List<Club>`, not a `List<String>`.